# MySQL MAX and MIN

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the following query

```
SELECT `id`, 
       `name`, 
       `ownerid`, 
       `creationdata`, 
       `motd`, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   guild_membership a, 
               players_online b 
        WHERE  a.player_id = b.player_id 
               AND a.guild_id = id) AS `online`, 
       (SELECT Max(b.level) 
        FROM   guild_membership a, 
               players b 
        WHERE  a.player_id = b.id 
               AND a.guild_id = id) AS `toplevel`, 
       (SELECT Min(a.level) 
        FROM   players a, 
               guild_membership b 
        WHERE  a.id = b.player_id 
               AND b.guild_id = id) AS `lowlevel` 
FROM   `guilds` 
WHERE  `name` = 'Wideswing Poleaxe' 
LIMIT  1;
```

The tables used in here are the followin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  KEY `vocation` (`vocation`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ownerid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creationdata` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `motd` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`ownerid`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`ownerid`) REFERENCES `players`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guild_membership` (
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `guild_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nick` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`guild_id`) REFERENCES `guilds` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`rank_id`) REFERENCES `guild_ranks` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I am trying to get the MAX level and MIN level on the players table inside one guild

However I am always getting toplevel and lowlevel the same value and tis always the lowest level

I am not sure what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I notice is: you are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. So from the guilds table you expect to find more than one entry for `name = 'Wideswing Poleaxe'`, but only look at the first the DBMS happens to find. Is this desired?

Next thing I see is the out-dated join syntax. Where did you get this from? A twenty year old book? No, stop, twenty years ago this syntax was already made redundant, so it must be even older ;-) Use explicit joins instead (`JOIN ... ON ...`)

As to your subqueries: You are comparing with `id` without any qualifier, so the DBMS will take this to be `guild_membership.id` or `players_online` resp. `players.id`, where you really want it to be `guild.id`. **This should explain that you get unexpected values.**

As to how the query is built: You could join to the aggregated player data instead. And use alias names that match the tables.

```
select 
  guilds.id, 
  guilds.name, 
  guilds.ownerid, 
  guilds.creationdata, 
  guilds.motd, 
  players.online, 
  players.toplevel, 
  players.lowlevel 
from guilds
left join
(
  select 
    gms.guild_id, 
    max(p.level) as toplevel, 
    min(p.level) as lowlevel, 
    sum((select count(*) from players_online po where po.player_id = p.id)) as online
  from guild_membership gms
  join players p on p.id = gms.player_id
  group by gms.guild_id
) players on players.guild_id = guilds.id
where guilds.name = 'Wideswing Poleaxe';
```

You can change the left outer join (`left join`) to an inner join (`join`), if you don't need to see guilds without any player.

Comment: Your 'online' field is probably only ever going to one or zero; and you are only guaranteed a specific one of those values (on the same set of data values) if all players are online or offline at the same time. (i.e. you don't need the sub-subquery).

Comment: @Uueerdo: If that were the case, the table `player` should either simply have a flag online yes/no or, for more data, have an `id_player_online`. But it's vice versa: The table `players_online` has an `id_player`, thus allowing for one player to be multiple times in that table. So my query matches the datamodel, but of course it may be a glitch in the model and then things could be as simple as you describe.

Comment: I was judging by how the original question used the `players_online` table; if it is as you were interpreting it, their original query would've gotten the total number of times players had been online. Either way, your `online` value is going to be fickle, since it's value neither aggregated or grouped by the the query containing the subquery it is calculated in; instead it will retrieve the number of times an effectively random player of that guild has been online.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Oops, you are right, I must sum it. Thank you for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here: `a.guild_id = id`

The id being used is from players, not guilds, as it is still part of the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need all those subqueries, JOINs are almost always faster and should usually be first technique tried.

Try this...

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `ownerid`, `creationdata`, `motd` 
       , COUNT(po.player_id) AS online
       , MAX(p.level) AS toplevel
       , MIN(p.level) AS lowlevel
FROM `guilds` AS g
LEFT JOIN guild_membership AS gm ON g.id = gm.guild_id
LEFT JOIN players AS p ON gm.player_id = p.player_id
LEFT JOIN players_online AS po ON gm.player_id = po.player_id
WHERE g.`name` = 'Wideswing Poleaxe'
;
```

`COUNT` only counts non-null values; similarly `MAX`, `MIN`, and most other aggregate functions ignore null values (only returning null if only null values were processed).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider modifying your query like

```
SELECT g.`id`, 
       g.`name`, 
       g.`ownerid`, 
       g.`creationdata`, 
       g.`motd`, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   guild_membership a, 
               players_online b 
        WHERE  a.player_id = b.player_id 
               AND a.guild_id = id) AS `online`, 
       (SELECT Max(b.level) 
        FROM   players b join guild_membership a on a.player_id = b.id 
               AND a.guild_id = g.id) AS `toplevel`, 
       (SELECT Min(a.level) 
        FROM   players a join 
               guild_membership b on a.id = b.player_id 
               AND b.guild_id = g.id) AS `lowlevel` 
FROM   `guilds` g
WHERE  g.`name` = 'Wideswing Poleaxe' 
LIMIT  1;
```